# Manipulate variables that were parsed from CSV file with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, csv

I'm a beginner to AJAX. My task is to parse data from a CSV file and call a function that is manipulating the data afterwards.

But I know, that I don't have access to the function when it's called.

I already googled but I couldn't find a sollution except parsing the CSV-file in PHP and then returning it to JS, but I don't like that sollution.

That's my code. It's simplified for convenience:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="MyFunction()"></button>
```

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "data.csv",
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(data) {
    //Parse CSV-file to Two-Dimensional Array
    var CSV = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var Data = []
    for (var count = 0; count < CSV.length; count++) {
      var this_line = []
      var cell_data = CSV[count].split(";");
      for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++) {
        this_line.push(cell_data[cell_count])
      }
      Data.push(this_line)
    };

    var MyVar = Data[2][2] // MyVar = 10

    function MyFunction() {
      MyVar++
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Do you want this Ajax to run when the button is clicked? In that cas, you need the `$.ajax(...)` to be *inside* the definition of `MyFunction`.